# The shutcut can't be used in firefox for jupyter-notebook

Tags: python

I'm using jupyter-notebook with firefox on Ubuntu 20.04. When I tape `B` `A` `dd`, I can't manage cells.
If I use google-chrome, I don't have that problem.

Comment: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5963

Comment: Years pass, nothing changes... Looks like they have been having that problem since 2019